# Does $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}$ exists???

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

does the limit exist for the following:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}$$

My take: I tried to substitute $z=x+iy$ for z and then solve the limit but I get 0. According to the [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20re(z%5E2)%2F%7Cz%7C%5E2,%20z%20-%3E%200) its limit is 1; so can someone please explain this to me? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank You!!!

Comment: Try specific sequences $(z_n)$ converging to zero, for example $z_n=\frac1n$ and $z_n=\frac in$. If the limit along these sequences is not the same, you know the whole limit does not exist, right?

Comment: @RodrigoPizarro No. (Please use "Hint" only for... well, hints.)

Comment: Try approaching $0$ along the real vs. imaginary axes to see that the limit doesn't exist. WA [agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+re((iz)%5E2)%2F%7Ciz%7C%5E2,+z+-%3E+0), which suggests that it's taking $\,z\,$ to be real in both cases..

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assume $z \not =0:$

$z=re^{i \phi}$; $r \not = 0$.

$Re(z^2)= r^2\cos (2 \phi)$; $|z^2|=r^2.$

Consider:

$ \dfrac {Re (z^2)}{|z^2|} = \dfrac {r^2 \cos(2\phi)}{r^2}= \cos(2\phi)$;

$\phi$ is arbitrary.

Does limit $r \rightarrow 0$ exist?

Comment: Very nice Peter!

Comment: Thanks, Gimusi.

Comment: We can also simplify further assuming $w=z^2$. But it doesn’t change so much!

Comment: Thanks , should not take long .

Comment: Take time to me since I’m very weak in topological issue!!! I need to study a little bit :)

Comment: Gimusi. Never mind. No rush. It is kind of beautiful , thanks .

Answer (score 1):

If $z \in \mathbb R$ and $z \ne 0$, then $\frac {Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}=1$

and

if $z \in i\mathbb R$ and $z \ne 0$, then $\frac {Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}=-1$

Conclusion ?

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying i.e. the limit d.n.e and I reached the same conclusion. I suppose I am only confused because wolfram alpha says otherwise so I thought I was mistaken somewhere...

Comment: What  wolfram alpha says is wrong.

Comment: @DevonPuchailo Did you read my comment under the main post, and followed the WA link in it? WA is not "*wrong*", it's just misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @dxiv I see what you meant now, it makes sense! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

take $$z_n = 1/n~~~ and ~~~~w_n=1/in$$

both sequences converge to $0$ but $$ \frac {Re(z_n^2)}{|z_n|^2}=1~~~~~and~~~~~\frac {Re(w_n^2)}{|w_n|^2}=-1$$

then the convergence is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Following your first idea, note that in algebraic form we obtain

$$ \frac {Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

which tends to

- 0 when moving along $x=y$
- 1 when moving along $y=0$

Thus $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {Re(z^2)}{|z|^2}$ does not exist.

Comment: Gimusi.Nice answer.

Comment: @PeterSzilas it is just an alternative way following his first attempt! Thanks